# Python Firebase SDK throws error "The registration token is not a valid FCM registration token"

Tags: python, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I have the following code snippet:

```
from firebase_admin import messaging
import firebase_admin
import os

os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "key.json"

default_app = firebase_admin.initialize_app()

# 129 chars
registration_token = "e2-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY_TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT-FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF-HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH"

message = messaging.Message(
    data={
        'score': '850',
        'time': '2:45',
    },
    token=registration_token,
)

response = messaging.send(message)
```

Which throws the following error:

```
...
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/***/messages:send

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

...
firebase_admin.exceptions.InvalidArgumentError: The registration token is not a valid FCM registration token
```

I have no idea why this token should be invalid? I checked online and the format seems OK and I don't have any other token. Target is an iOS App.